# R Plot not showing if inside function

Tags: r, ggplot2

If I run the following code, everything works as expected and the plot shows on the right panel in RStudio:

```r
plot(x=iris$Sepal.Width, y=iris$Sepal.Length)
```

However, if instead I call the plot from my own custom function, it no longer shows the plot. Why?

```r
a <- function() {
  plot(x=iris$Sepal.Width, y=iris$Sepal.Length)
}

a
```

EDIT: As per the comments, I forgot to call `a` as `a()`. However, I have another scenario in which, once again, the plot is not being created, and I do not know why, this time with ggplot:

```r
a <- function() {
  ggplot(iris, aes(x=Sepal.Width, y=Sepal.Length)) +
    geom_point()
  
  return(1)
}

b <- a()
```

If I return a value from the function, the plot is not created.

Comment: Are you actually calling the function with `a()` rather than just `a`?

Comment: Thank you for the help, it now works. However, I added another scenario in my edit that still does not work

Comment: Well, now that's a different question. The `ggplot` function doesn't actually draw a plot. It returns an option that draw a plot when that object is printed. If you return the object from the function, R will normally print that for you. But if you don't return the value, you'll need to explicitly `print()` the result yourself

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answer pre-edit:

That is not a function call (if we're talking R), that is an implicit `print` of `a`. Try `a()` instead of simply `a`.

Answer post-edit:

As @MrFlick mentioned in his comment, the result of `ggplot` should be printed, either implicitly (by evaluating its output at the console), or explicitly. The second example avoids the evaluation of the `ggplot` result at console (by returning `1` instead), so the only option left is explicit printing:

```
library("ggplot2")

a <- function() {
    print(
        ggplot(iris, aes(x=Sepal.Width, y=Sepal.Length))
      + geom_point()
    )
    return(1)
}

b <- a()
```

Comment: Yeah, you are completely correct. Check my edit for another scenario with ggplot that still does not work as expected